# Run-Time Error 1100 when trying to "SelectAll" in ProjApp_ProjectBeforeTaskChange (inside Class Module)

Tags: vba, ms-project

**Goal**: I am trying to save all the Task's `UniqueID`, and `Text5` values before a `Change` event occurs.

Therefore, I have a Class Module `clsTskUpdate`, where I try to save all these values inside a `Dictionary` in `ProjApp_ProjectBeforeTaskChange` event.

**However**, since I have a Master-Project, and several Sub-Projects, I need to `SelectAll` tasks, and loop through `ActiveSelection.Tasks` to get their `UniqueID` inside the Master-Project (thanks to the help of @Rachel Hettinger).

The problem starts, that whenever I modify the value of `ActualFinish` from the Combo-Box (as shown in the screen-shot Below):

[image]

I get a Run-time error '1100':

> The method is not available in this situation

At the following line (inside `Sub ProjApp_ProjectBeforeTaskChange`)

```
SelectAll
```

Does anyone here know how to handle it ? How can I use the `SelectAll` before the task update it's values to save all of the current values in my `Dictionary` ?

***Class clsTskUpdate* Code**

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents ProjApp   As Application

Private Sub ProjApp_ProjectBeforeTaskChange(ByVal Tsk As Task, ByVal Field As PjField, ByVal NewVal As Variant, Cancel As Boolean)

RowIDChanged = Tsk.UniqueID
MsgBox Application.StatusBar
SaveStatusforAllTasks ' call SaveStatusforAllTasks Sub, which saves current status of Text5 ("Status") of all tasks

End Sub

'===================================================================
Sub SaveStatusforAllTasks()

Dim AllTasks As Tasks
Dim Tsk As Task

' ****** Get Error 1100 at the line below *****
SelectAll
Set AllTasks = ActiveSelection.Tasks

' add existing values of UniqueID and Text5 to Dictionary object
Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For Each Tsk In AllTasks
    If Not Tsk Is Nothing Then
        If Not Dict.exists(Tsk.UniqueID) Then
            Dict.Add Tsk.UniqueID, Tsk.Text5
        End If
    End If
Next Tsk

End Sub
```

***This Project* Code**

```
Private Sub Project_Change(ByVal pj As Project)

StatusRYGFieldUpdate

End Sub
```

**Regular Module Code**

```
Option Explicit

Public StatusRYGView                As New clsTskUpdate
Public RowIDChanged                 As Long
Public Const myDateFormat           As String = "dd/mm/yy"
Public Dict As Object ' use a Dictionary to save previous values of all UniqueID and Text5 values ("Status")


Sub StatusRYGFieldUpdate()

Set StatusRYGView.ProjApp = Application
PaneClose ' should close the Split window (to make sure run-time error 1100 won't happen

Application.Calculation = pjManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

If UpdateViewFlag Then
    FormatModifiedTasks ' call FormatModifiedTasks Sub, which updates all tasks that Text5 ("Status") were modified
End If

Application.Calculation = pjAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: What do you do with saved Text5 values?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to just save the value of Text5 before the task is changed (for any field), then try this:

```
Private Sub ProjApp_ProjectBeforeTaskChange(ByVal tsk As Task, ByVal Field As PjField, _
    ByVal NewVal As Variant, Cancel As Boolean)

    If Not dict.Exists(tsk.UniqueID) Then
        dict.Add tsk.UniqueID, tsk.Text5
    Else
        dict(tsk.UniqueID) = tsk.Text5
    End If

End Sub
```

`tsk.UniqueID` will be the unique value within the master project (e.g. 8388611, rather than 3).

Comment: Following our previous post (which you've help solve), I need to loop on selection. and I can't use `SelectAll` in the mode I've shared in my screen-shot (in my post), I have no problem saving the value into the Dictionary

Comment: Save all the values at a different time--not in the Change event--perhaps on project open.  Also, there is no way to disable events in Project like there is in Excel, so be careful not to trigger additional events within the Change event code.